# C# How to sort combobox items by date

Tags: c#, sql, database, combobox

```
    void Fillcombo()
    {
        cbxProducts.Text = "";
        cbxProducts.Items.Clear();
        string constring = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\hannes.corbett\\Desktop\\Barcode Scanning\\Barcode Scanning\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
        string Query = "SELECT Name FROM Products;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                cbxProducts.Items.Add(sName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

[What the database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOHFb.png)

I can't figure out how to sort the items listed in the combobox by their date while just displaying their Name

Comment: Sort in your query by "ORDER BY"

Comment: Extend your query with an `Order by Name`

Comment: If you really want to do it in code instead SQL, add the values to a list and then sort it

Comment: Change your query from `SELECT Name FROM Products;` to `SELECT Name FROM Products ORDER BY eDate;`

Comment: like this? `  string Query = "SELECT Name FROM Products ORDER BY EDate;";`

Comment: I did that but it donsn't seem to work

Comment: NVM it worked when i added 'cbxProducts.Sorted = false;'

Comment: This question is too basic sql but i don't know what close-vote reason i could pick

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think we should close-vote basic questions just for being basic. We all where it the OP's place once. Even basic questions deserves answers. Admittedly, most basic question should not be asked in the first place, since a simple research will give the answer, however sometimes you don't even know what to search for...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: OP even knew the answer himself, he didn't need to search. I agree, basic questions deserve an answer if they are somehow unique. But it's hard to find a duplicate for a question "how can i sort my databse records" because it's so obvious and can be answered by every sql tutorial.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree. I was just pointing out that being basic is not always a good reason for closing a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    void Fillcombo()
    {
        cbxProducts.Text = "";
        cbxProducts.Items.Clear();
        string constring = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\hannes.corbett\\Desktop\\Barcode Scanning\\Barcode Scanning\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
        string Query = "SELECT Name FROM Products ORDER BY EDate;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                cbxProducts.Items.Add(sName);
                cbxProducts.Sorted = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This fixed it for me

Comment: Yes indeed, an `ORDER BY` is the perfect way to sort items in the database. But this is not really a C# and even less a combobox question. It's also not new and very basic sql question.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dates before adding them to the combobox. Using "ORDER BY", the content is sorted by the String representation.

Make sure to turn of auto sorting.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/163bd5b3-b439-435f-b87e-c7f7431f4978/how-to-sort-combobox-with-dates?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourObject : IComparable{
public YourObject(string name) {
    Name = name;
}
public string Name { get; set; }
public override string ToString()
{
    return GetHashCode().ToString() + "_" + Name;
}

#region IComparable Members

public int CompareTo(Object other)
{
    return Comparer.Default.Compare(this.ToString(), other.ToString());
}

#endregion
```

}